# How to control for an independent variable in logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, prediction

I am trying to predict the Spotify popularity score using a range of machine learning algorithms in the R Caret package including logistic regression. The aim is to predict track popularity based on audio features e.g. danceability, energy etc. The problem I have is that Spotify are not transparent about how the popularity score is calculated but I know it is based on a number of things including play counts and how recent the track is. That means that the number of days released will have an impact on the popularity score so I have included days_released as an independent variable in my modelling to try and control for it.

So, I have 50 variables (days_released being one of them). I am using the rfe function in Caret to perform feature selection but for every algorithm, days_released is the only variable selected. Does anyone have any advice or recommended reading on how to overcome this problem? I want to predict popularity and explore which track features have a significant relationship with popularity, controlling for days_released.

Do I take the days_released variable out altogether?

Do I leave it in but force rfe to select more than one feature?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a simple logistic regression in base R? It would be useful to see how well each of these features associate with popularity. Perhaps you could follow some of these answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17336/how-exactly-does-one-control-for-other-variables

Comment: Thanks @AdamWaring - I have tried simple logistic regression and it appears to perform quite well - there are a number of track audio features that appear to be significant while including/controlling for days_released. The link you have sent confirms that just including days_released in the logistic regression model will control for it however do you know if the case is the same for other techniques e.g. random forest or neural networks? Thanks in advance!